# Get first n customers with highest value spend within a month of their registration

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:
'Orders' table contains:
order_id,
order_ts,
customer_ts,
usd_value

'Customers' table contains:
customer_id,
registered_ts

What I've done so far is to get all customers registered in April 2020:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, o.order_value_usd, c.registered_ts
FROM customers c, orders o
WHERE c.customer_id=o.customer_id 
AND c.registered_ts BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-05-01'
```

I need to get the top 10 customers with the highest total orders in the first month and who registered in May 2020. Below I posted input tables and expected output.

Customers table:

| customer_id | registered_ts |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | 2018-01-12 |
| 21 | 2020-05-01 |
| 22 | 2020-05-02 |
| 23 | 2020-05-03 |
| 24 | 2020-05-03 |
| 25 | 2020-05-03 |
| 26 | 2020-05-03 |
| 27 | 2020-05-04 |
| 28 | 2020-05-05 |
| 29 | 2020-05-06 |
| 30 | 2020-05-06 |
| 31 | 2020-05-06 |
| 32 | 2020-05-06 |

Orders table:

| order_id | order_ts | customer_id | usd_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 2019-02-06 | 18 | 200 |
| 41 | 2020-06-20 | 27 | 100 |
| 42 | 2020-06-01 | 27 | 200 |
| 43 | 2020-06-02 | 28 | 200 |
| 44 | 2020-06-02 | 28 | 50 |
| 45 | 2020-06-02 | 29 | 400 |
| 46 | 2020-06-03 | 30 | 500 |
| 47 | 2020-06-04 | 31 | 500 |
| 48 | 2020-06-05 | 32 | 600 |
| 49 | 2020-06-06 | 21 | 150 |

Output:

| customer_id | registered_ts | usd_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27 | 2020-05-04 | 200 |
| 28 | 2020-05-05 | 250 |
| 29 | 2020-05-06 | 400 |
| 30 | 2020-05-06 | 500 |
| 31 | 2020-05-06 | 500 |
| 32 | 2020-05-06 | 600 |

Comment: you can use SELECT TOP(10) order by value desc where date > start_date and date < end date

Comment: @StefanAvramovic `top` is not the tagged *MySql* syntax

Comment: can you share sample input tables and expected output? @Siriguuu

Comment: Is this the only output you want or you have shown sample output?

Comment: I have shown a sample output

Comment: Please update the full output from this sample data.

Comment: I updated the full output for this sample

Answer (score 0):

I think this will cover it..
inner join will remove null values if there are less than 10 resaults with usd_value

```
    SELECT max(b.usd_value) as usd_value, a.customer_id, a.registered_ts
    FROM Customers a
    INNER JOIN Orders b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
    WHERE registered_ts BETWEEN "2020-05-01" and  "2020-06-01"
    GROUP BY a.customer_id, a.registered_ts 
    LIMIT 10
```

To get orders made within a month since the user registered
just edit the join,
if the month is 06 then just add MONTH(a.registered_ts) + 1

```
       SELECT max(b.usd_value) as usd_value, a.customer_id, a.registered_ts
        FROM Customers a
        INNER JOIN Orders b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
          AND YEAR(a.registered_ts) = YEAR(b.order_ts) 
          AND MONTH(a.registered_ts) = MONTH(b.order_ts) 
        GROUP BY a.customer_id, a.registered_ts 
        LIMIT 10;
```

If you want to check 15 days prior and 15 days past registration date, you can do:

```
SELECT max(b.usd_value) as usd_value, a.customer_id, a.registered_ts
FROM Customers a
INNER JOIN Orders b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
  AND   DATE( b.order_ts)  > DATE(a.registered_ts - INTERVAL 15 day)
  AND   DATE( b.order_ts)  < DATE(a.registered_ts + INTERVAL 15 day)
GROUP BY a.customer_id, a.registered_ts 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost works perfectly. However, I only need to take into consideration the orders made within a month since the user registered.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as the correct one :)